# How do I Highlight a area with Google Maps JavaScript API v3 in asp.net MVC, I have only Lat and Lang.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

[this is the highlighted region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bUw6.jpg)

I want to highlight a area like on the image below which is taken from Google Maps. Is this possible to accomplish with the current version of their API (v3)? If yes, how

Answer (score 0):

You might use html / javascript to do it.

In html you have the `<area>` tag which you can drawn a polygon indicating some coords with the benefits of easy html markup. Find more [info here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_area_tag.htm).

You may find [this JavaScript plugin](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) usefull too, particularly its `stroke` settings.

But, maybe, the easiest way is to edit image with your favorite photo editor and then, after done, add any behaviours you might need.

If you could try to be more specific on your actuall needs, we could try to help you better! :)

Comment: But sir  I want to this functionality with google map  API ,i have no idea how to get coordinate of particular region and i have only lat and log of area.how to highlight region of city/district in Indian map.

Comment: It only depends if Google's API lets you to do that, I'm not sure if API itself gives you that methods to do that (just take a look on it's documentation to know), but, at least, you have a workarround to get the same result as well

Comment: Share your solution as answer so all comunity users can learn from it too. Thank you